# Quantificational vs Referential vs Predicational descriptions

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-language, analytic-philosophy, bertrand-russell, frege

Reading Peter Ludlow's [article](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/descriptions/#WhaRemTheDes) on descriptions, it's clear to me that descriptions can be interpreted, found or considered in 3 different ways. They can be seen as quantificational, referential or predicational expressions.  This division applies both to definite and indefinite descriptions.

However, the article isn't quite clear on how the 3 approaches arose. If Russell was, of course, the mind behind the quantificational approach, it remains vague who were responsible for the others.

How did the 3 different approaches come about?

What are some examples of propositions expressing the 3 different interpretations?

When and who were the first ones who proposed each interpretation?

---

Ludlow, Peter, "Descriptions", The Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy (Summer 2018 Edition), Edward N. Zalta (ed.), URL = https://plato.stanford.edu/archives/sum2018/entries/descriptions/.

Comment: I edited, sorry for the mistakes

Comment: For the predicational approach, SEP's entry has a very simple example: " 'John is not a lawyer' does not seem to have the meaning that there is a lawyer such that John is not identical to that lawyer. It is more natural to take an utterance of [it] as denying that John has a certain property."

Comment: I presume that with "referential" approach you are considering theories like that of [Alexius Meinong](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/meinong/) according to which a expressions like ‘the Present King of France’ refer to non-existent objects.

Comment: You can see Nicholas Griffin & Dale Jacquette (editors), [Russell vs Meinong: The Legacy of "On Denoting"](https://books.google.it/books?id=jUiSAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover), Routledge (2009) as well as Dale Jacquette, [Alexius Meinong: The Shepherd of Non-Being](https://books.google.it/books?id=7jswCgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover), Springer (2015).